# angular js revert change of scope property inside a watch statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a select box that triggers an http PUT when it's changed.

#### html:

```
<select ng-model='color'></select>
```

#### js:

```
$scope.$watch('color', function(newValue, oldValue) { 
    $http.put('...', {color: newValue})   
});
```

The issue is that if the http request fails for whatever reason I want the select box to revert to it's previous value.

```
 $scope.$watch('color', function(newValue, oldValue) { 
    req = $http.put('...', {color: newValue})
    req.error(function(){
      $scope.color = oldValue  // will probably cause the $watch to get triggered again (bad)
    });   
});
```

This will probably cause the $watch function to get triggered again which is not desirable as it would trigger an unnecessary PUT.

How can I revert the value without triggering the $watch function again?

Answer (score 8):

Use `ng-change` to submit the changes to the server and revert back to the previous value if the put fails.

#### Html

```
<select ng-model='color' ng-change="changeColor()"></select>
```

#### Controller

```
 $scope.$watch('color', function(newValue, oldValue) { 
      $scope.previousColor = oldValue;
 });

 $scope.changeColor = function(){
    $http.put('...', {color:  $scope.color}).error(function(){
      $scope.color =  $scope.previousColor;
    });   
 };
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/l4HDkpBSsryb26NLzNSc?p=preview)

Comment: why do u suggest ng change over watch..i saw someone else also saying this on SO